# Delegate optional argument resolution in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, if I have a function that calls a constructor (or another function) is there a way to delegate the determination of default argument to the underlying constructor/function?

This syntax isn't valid, but hopefully this illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
fun buildMyObject(stringParam: String?, intParam: Int?): MyClass {
    return MyClass(stringParam, intParam)
}

class MyClass(val stringParam: String = "Hello world!", val intParam: Int = 42)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no support for exactly what you want. However, if you have a bit of flexibility about where `buildMyObject` lives, you can have something like:

```
class MyClass(val stringParam: String = defaultString, val intParam: Int = defaultInt) {

    private constructor(stringParam: String?, intParam: Int?) : this(
            stringParam ?: defaultString,
            intParam ?: defaultInt
    )

    companion object {
        private const val defaultString = "Hello world!"
        private const val defaultInt = 42

        fun buildMyObject(stringParam: String?, intParam: Int?): MyClass {
            return MyClass(stringParam, intParam)
        }
    }
}
```

This has a couple of nice characteristics:

- Lets users still call the null-safe `MyClass` constructor
- Doesn't duplicate where the default values are defined
- Doesn't grow exponentially in the number of constructors you'd need if you'd try to use a `when` and call with or without each param (imagine what would happen if you'd add a third parameter!)
- Keeps the nullable constructor private, so callers can only use nullables if they go through the factory method

Comment: Darn. I was hoping there'd be a straightforward way to do delegation. This is very close to what I ended up using. Thanks for taking the time to write up the example!